# Using Triggers to create new values with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have multiple tables that I want create new rows of information when information is added to the original table. Are triggers the way to go for this in PHPMyAdmin? I know how to update it from the website, but I want to be able to create a row of information from the website, and then in PHPMyAdmin, it will automatically update all of the tables dependent on that row.

For example. I have three tables (simplified versions):

HotelType ( HotelTypeID , HotelTypeName ) **a type of hotel, not an actual hotel, every resort has every type of hotel

Resort ( ResortID , Address )

ResortHotel ( ResortHotelID , ResortID , HotelTypeID ) **the actual hotel, the unique combinations of all hotels and all resorts.

For example, Resort 2 will have all types of Hotels, but to choose a specific hotel, I would choose the ResortHotelID that corresponds to Resort 2 and the type of hotel that I want.

If a HotelType is created, it should enter a new line of information into 'ResortHotel' with the HotelTypeID for every existing Resort that there is.

I am new to PHP and MySQL, so I tried to do this all through the website initially and received 'Fatal error: maximum execution time'. So I am sure there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is usually used for database administrators to manage a MySQL (or MariaDB) instance; it's not great for allowing end users to insert or manage data. So you probably ought to do this in your custom application rather than phpMyAdmin.

However, if you're getting a maximum execution timeout while just inserting a row, something isn't right (either with the server or with your query). I also suggest investigating that problem.

To answer the heart of your question, it sounds like you can do that with a trigger, stored procedure, or in your application code. Note that none of those options is dependent on phpMyAdmin; triggers and stored procedures exist in MySQL/MariaDB and can execute without phpMyAdmin.